# Obtaining index based on connditions

Tags: python, pandas

From the following code:

```
aps1.Status.head(10)
Out[663]: 
0    OK
1    OK
2    OK
3    OK
4    OK
5    OK
6    Fail
7    OK
8    Fail
9    OK
```

How to obtain the indexes for which Status is Fail? I tried:

```
 print (index for index,value in enumerate(aps1.Status) if value == "Fail"])
```

But I'm getting syntax error. Thanks

Comment: Use `aps1.index[aps1.Status.eq('Fail')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `index`:

```
L = aps1.index[aps1.Status == 'Fail']
```

Comment: As always to the rescue!

Answer (score 2):

remove the ']' at the end

```
print (index for index,value in enumerate(aps1.Status) if value == "Fail"**]**)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because of the extra ] . Try deleting it

Answer (score 0):

use a list comprehension with a iterrows on the dataframe with an if condition for Status column

```
status=['OK'
,'OK'
,'OK'
,'OK'
,'OK'
,'OK'
,'Fail'
,'OK'
,'Fail'
,'OK']
df=pd.DataFrame({'Status':status})
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print([index for index,item in df.iterrows() if item['Status']=='Fail'])
```

output
[6, 8]